# R Spanish Term Frequency Matrix with TD and Quanteda Spanish Characters

Tags: r, special-characters, encode, quanteda

I am trying to learn how to do some text analysis with twitter data. I am running into an issue when creating a Term Frequency Matrix. 
I create the Corpus out of spanish text (with special characters), with no issues.

However, when I create the Term Frequency Matrix (either with quanteda or tm libraries) the spanish characters do not display as expected (instead of seeing canción, I see canciÃ³n).

Any suggestions on how I can get the Term Frequency Matrix to store the text with the correct characters?

Thank you for any help.

As a note: I prefer using the quanteda library, since ultimately I will be creating a wordcloud, and I think I better understand this library's approach. I am also using a Windows machine.

I have tried Encoding(tw2)  <- "UTF-8" with no luck.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tm)
library(quanteda)

#' Creating a character with special Spanish characters:
tw2 <- "RT @None: Enmascarados, si masduro chingán a tarek. Si quieres ahora, la aguantas canción  . https://t."


#Cleaning the tweet, removing special punctuation, numbers http links, 
extra spaces:
clean_tw2 <- tolower(tw2)
clean_tw2 = gsub("&amp", "", clean_tw2)
clean_tw2 = gsub("(rt|via)((?:\\b\\W*@\\w+)+)", "", clean_tw2)
clean_tw2 = gsub("@\\w+", "", clean_tw2)
clean_tw2 = gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", clean_tw2)
clean_tw2 = gsub("http\\w+", "", clean_tw2)
clean_tw2 = gsub("[ \t]{2,}", "", clean_tw2)
clean_tw2 = gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", clean_tw2) 

# creates a vector with common stopwords, and other words which I want removed.
myStopwords <- c(stopwords("spanish"),"tarek","vez","ser","ahora")
clean_tw2 <- (removeWords(clean_tw2,myStopwords))

# If we print clean_tw2 we see that all the characters are displayed as expected.
clean_tw2

#'Create Corpus Using quanteda library
corp_quan<-corpus(clean_tw2)
# The corpus created via quanteda, displays the characters as expected.
corp_quan$documents$texts

#'Create Corpus Using TD library
corp_td<-Corpus(VectorSource(clean_tw2))
#' Remove common words from spanish from the Corpus.
#' If we inspect the corp_td, we see that the characters and words are displayed correctly
inspect(corp_td)

# Create the DFM with quanteda library.
tdm_quan<-dfm(corp_quan)
# Here we see that the spanish characters are displayed incorrectly for Example: canción = canciÃ³n
tdm_quan

# Create the TDM with TD library
tdm_td<-TermDocumentMatrix(corp_td)

# Here we see that the Spanish characters are displayed incorrectly (e.g. canción = canciÃ), and "si" is missing.
tdm_td$dimnames$Terms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like quanteda (and tm) is losing the encoding when creating the DFM on the windows platform. In [this tidytext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47715807/does-tidytextunnest-tokens-works-with-spanish-characters) question the same problem happens with unnesting tokens. Which works fine now and also `quanteda`'s `tokens` works fine. 
If I enforce `UTF-8` or `latin1` encoding on the `@Dimnames$features` of the `dfm` you get the correct results.

```
....
previous code
.....
tdm_quan<-dfm(corp_quan)
# Here we see that the spanish characters are displayed incorrectly for Example: canción = canciÃ³n
tdm_quan
Document-feature matrix of: 1 document, 8 features (0% sparse).
1 x 8 sparse Matrix of class "dfm"
       features
docs    enmascarados si masduro chingÃ¡n quieres aguantas canciÃ³n t
  text1            1  2       1        1       1        1        1 1
```

If you do the following:

```
Encoding(tdm_quan@Dimnames$features) <- "UTF-8"
tdm_quan
Document-feature matrix of: 1 document, 8 features (0% sparse).
1 x 8 sparse Matrix of class "dfm"
       features
docs    enmascarados si masduro chingán quieres aguantas canción t
  text1            1  2       1       1       1        1       1 1
```

Comment: Thank you phiver. Forcing the encoding worked like a charm. 
Once I get my hands on an OSx I will try the original code and see if the original code works. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess...are you using Windows?  On macOS it works fine:

```
clean_tw2
## [1] "enmascarados si masduro chingán   si quieres   aguantas canción"
Encoding(clean_tw2)
## [1] "UTF-8"
dfm(clean_tw2)
## Document-feature matrix of: 1 document, 7 features (0% sparse).
## 1 x 7 sparse Matrix of class "dfm"
##        features
## docs    enmascarados si masduro chingán quieres aguantas canción
##   text1            1  2       1       1       1        1       1
```

My system information:

```
sessionInfo()
# R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
# Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
# Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.4
# 
# Matrix products: default
# BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
# LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
# 
# locale:
# [1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8
# 
# attached base packages:
# [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
# 
# other attached packages:
# [1] tm_0.7-3       NLP_0.1-11     dplyr_0.7.4    quanteda_1.1.6
```

Comment: @Ken Benoit, might this be an issue with the to / from C++  travel?

Comment: Check `Encoding(clean_tw)` before you send that to `corpus()`.

Comment: On my machine that is `UTF-8`. Also `Encoding(corp_quan$documents$texts)` is `UTF-8`.  But if I look at `Encoding(tdm_quan@Dimnames$features)` the result is unknown.